# Merge nodes in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, ttk

**How can one merge two nodes in a `tkinter` treeview widget?**

Suppose you have this simple structure in your treeview:

```
-Parent1
   -Child1
-Parent2
   -Child2
```

And you want to merge the two parent items to create the following structure:

```
-Parent1
   -Child1
   -Child2
```

The `iid`'s of the parent nodes are known. Basically it is a transfer of the children nodes to one parent to the other and a deletion of the parent left without children. Is there a way implemented in `tkinter` to do so or do you have to define something yourself?

Sample code creating the basic example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(
    root,
    selectmode='browse'
)
tree.insert('', 0, iid=1, text='Parent1')
tree.insert('', 0, iid=2, text='Parent2')

tree.insert(1, 0, text='Child 1')
tree.insert(2, 0, text='Child 2')

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tree.move()` to move 'Child 2' to 'Parent 1':

```py
tree.move(child2, 1, 'end')
```

where `child2` is the `iid` of 'Child 2':

```
child2 = tree.insert(2, 0, text='Child 2')
```

Then delete 'Parent 2':

```py
tree.delete(2)
```